# python pandas dataFrame create single json column of multiple columns value

Tags: python, json, pandas

In python pandas dataFrame i wanted create single json column of multiple columns value.

Assuming following dataFrame:
**Example:**

```
| -   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4|
| 1   | abc  | def  | ghi  |  8  |
| 2   | xab  | xcd  | xef  |  9  |
```

**This is the result i want.**

```
|     |col1 | json_col|br
|1    | abc |   {"col2":"def","col3":"ghi","col4":8}|
|2    | xab |   {"col2":"xcd","col3":"xef","col4":9}|
```

How can i create the single column(json type) of selected columns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html), last remove columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
cols = ['col2','col3','col4']
df['json_col'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
   - col1                              json_col
0  1  abc  {"col2":"def","col3":"ghi","col4":8}
1  2  xab  {"col2":"xcd","col3":"xef","col4":9}
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, this method is failing when I want to convert only 1 column. I get this error: 
`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'to_json'`
Can you please consider this case and let me know how to do it?

Comment: @ShantanuJain It'll work if you put the one column into a list, like when you're passing a list of more than 1 columns.